# Вставка текста в середину файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Есть текстовый файл с разделением наподобие этого:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6
```

Как можно вставить дополнительный текст между определённым числом и `|`?

К примеру, мне нужно вставить текст `чтонибудь` после числа `3`:

```
1|2|3/чтонибудь|4|5|6
```

Comment: Можно сплитнуть строку, можно регексом реплейснуть. Демократия

Comment: Файл придётся перезаписывать полностью, текст - это не таблица БД. Так что: всё прочитать, откорректировать, всё записАть.

Comment: можно и с перезаписью, но по идеи можно просто сохранять результат в отдельный файлик скажем

Comment: Да, всё записать в другой файл - не запрещается.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('in.txt', 'rt') as in_f:
   with open('out.txt', 'wt') as out_f:
      for line in in_f:
         # out.write(line.replace('|3|', '|3|что нибудь|')
         lst = line.split('|')
         out_f.write('|'.join(lst[:3] + ['что нибудь'] + lst[3:]))
```

Comment: дело в том, что 3 всегда разное (там разный текст)

Comment: т.е нужно определить позицию по разделителю и указать, что мы добавляем именно в конец /чтонибудь| до закрытия разделителя

Comment: @SergeyShcherbakov яснее формулируйте вопрос. Тогда так.

Comment: хм, по виду всё правильно, я не мог найти части:  lst = line.split('|') и out.write('|'.join(lst[:3] + ['что нибудь'] + lst[3:]))

Comment: но сейчас пишет:  

 File "run.py", line 1
    with open(‘in.txt’, 'rt') as in:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: @SergeyShcherbakov упс, сорри, `in` - ключевое слово

Comment: работает! ;) но оно дописывает к |3|чтонибудь| , а нужно что бы было  |3чтонибудь|